# node.js - Parsing a specific table in a html page that has multiple tables using cheerio

Tags: javascript, dom, cheerio

Here is my sample html.

```
<table class = "one">
  <thead>..</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>"Element 1<td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class = "one">
  <thead>..</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>"Element 2<td>
      <td>"Element 3<td>          
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am using cheerio to parse through the tables but unfortunately, I am not able to select a specific table as the tables do not have any ids or belong to different classes. 
The below code pulls all the rows from both the tables. I had to compare the output with known elements (for example "element2") to fix up an index that I can use to identify tables. But is there any better way using cheerio to pick up the first table on the page or just the second table on the page?

```
var $ = cheerio.load(sampleHTML);
$('table tr').each(function (i, element) { ..}
```

Comment: Have you tried the nth selector: `'table:nth-child(2) tr'` ? This example will select the tr's from the second table. More info: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_nthchild.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple methods:

1) Use a `:first-of-type`, `:last-of-type`, `:nth-of-type(n)`, `:first-child`, `:last-child`, or `nth-child(n)` selector. Some examples:

```
// to select rows in table 1:
$('table:first-of-type tr')
$('table:nth-child(1) tr')

// to select rows in table 2:
$('table:nth-of-type(2) tr')
$('table:last-child tr')
```

2) Use the built-in `.first()`, `.last()`, or `.eq(n)` filtering methods (or `.filter()` itself). With these, you'd select all `table`s, filter down to the `table` you want, then find all `tr`s in that table.

```
// to select rows in table 1:
$('table').first().find('tr')
$('table').eq(0).find('tr')

// to select rows in table 2:
$('table').last().find('tr')
$('table').filter(i => i === 1).find('tr')
```

Comment: Perfect! Tried the second method of filtering. Worked like a charm. Thanks